# Reverting to previous MR and incorporating from select future commits already in main branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-revert, merge-request

Some dependencies we merged into our main are now proving to have many downstream impacts.

At this point, the MR that updated these dependencies is previous to several newer MRs.

So if I have MR's as such:

```
336!
337!
338!
```

I need to revert to `336!` merge in `338!`.

**Proposed Solution**
I think I will create a `bugfix` branch that is an initial pull from `336!`. Then I will merge `338!` into my new `bugfix` branch. Test it of course, and then Merge this branch into the `master`.

This will inherently overwrite the changes that were made in `337!`? Or will merging in `338!` merge in `337!` changes as well?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to [revert 337](https://www.drupaldump.com/gitlab-revert-reverted-merge) in a `bugfix` branch created from main.

Initially, that `bugfix` branch includes all main history, including your 3 MRs.

But, by reverting 337!, you would:

- add a new commit cancelling 337 changes
- keep 336 and 338
- resolve in that branch any merge conflicts and test if everything still work.

So:

```
git switch -c bugfix main
git revert <3371 merge commit>
# test
git switch main
git merge --no-ff bugfix
```

Then you merge `bugfix` to `main`.

Comment: Thanks for this. In this sequence above, after reverting to `336!` at one point do I just merge in `338!` and skip over `337!`?

Comment: @Hofbr The bugfix branch already include 337 and 338, so nothing to merge in bugfix. You just have to merge bugfix to main.

Comment: Got it. My question may have been unclear but in my scenario `337!` is the problematic one. So I'm trying to revert to `336!` and incorporate `338!`.

Comment: @Hofbr then simply git revert 337. Since the branch already include 336 and 338, those are incorporated.